# Bluetooth File Transfer on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, share, file-transfer

I have been trying to write a program for transferring a file which the user selects from a **ListView** that i provide to the user. Once the user selects a file which he intends to transfer (*"I achieved that using **onLongClickListener**"*), this particular block of code is triggered:

```
    String mimeType = fileAction.getMimeType(rowHolder.get(position).getLabel());
            Intent playFile = new Intent();
            playFile.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Uri pathUri = Uri.parse("file://" + currentPath +     rowHolder.get(position).getLabel());
        playFile.setDataAndType(pathUri, mimeType);
        startActivity(playFile);
```

The trouble is that when I select the Bluetooth option from the list of options of applications which can handle this type of Intent ["*This part is automatic*"] nothing happens. This problem is only occurring when I am clicking on Bluetooth. All the other options like GMail, Bump, etc are working perfectly. Any help/Guidance would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance. Also, this is my Manifest File in case it seems that the sets of permissions is less than required. AndroidManifest File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="org.sample.test"
  android:versionCode="2"
  android:versionName="1.1">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name=".Preferences"
        android:label="@string/preferences" >
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name=".SearchFileSystem"
        android:label="@string/search" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data 
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>

</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code::Refer this [LINK](http://www.mikenimer.com/?p=373)

```
String mimeType = fileAction.getMimeType(rowHolder.get(position).getLabel());
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
intent.setType(mimeType);
Uri pathUri = Uri.parse("file://" + currentPath + rowHolder.get(position).getLabel());
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(pathUri ) );  
startActivity(intent);
```

Updated::

```
File file = new File(Path.toString());  
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimeType);
```

Comment: its asking to change type of "pathUri" to File

Comment: No worries got it. Thanks. :-). I was stuck on this for quite sometime.